# return minimum point in a range of points in CSV data using AWK

Tags: csv, awk, range, point, minimum

I want to return the minimum y value observed within a specified range of x values in CSV x, y data using AWK in Bash. So, specifically, I may have data such as the following:

```
xyData="10, 100
20, 200
30, 300
40, 400
50, 500
60, 600
70, 700
80, 800
90, 900
100, 1000"
```

I would want to ask a question such as the following: What is the point at which the minimum y value is observed in the range of points starting with x value 50 and ending with x value 90? The answer for this example would be "50, 500", because 500 is the minimum y value observed in the inclusive range of points starting with x value 50 and ending with x value 90.

I'm very new to AWK. Is there some nifty way in which this may be accomplished? Thank you very much for your assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (**EDIT: Solution with bugs, see *Scrutinizer's* comment**):

```
awk -F'[, ]+' '
  $1 >= 50 && $1 <= 90 { 
    if (y > $2 || y == 0) { 
      y = $2; x = $1 
    } 
  } 
  END { 
    printf "%s, %s\n", x, y 
  }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
50, 500
```

---

**UPDATE** the solution based in the comment of *Scrutinizer*:

```
awk -F'[, ]+' '
  $1 >= 50 && $1 <= 90 { 
    if (y > $2 || !y_set) { 
      y = $2 
      x = $1
      y_set = 1
    } 
  } 
  END {
    if ( x || y ) {
      printf "%s, %s", x, y 
    }
  }
' infile
```

Comment: This is very nice and clear. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: @Birei Suppose the y=0 for x=50 is 0, then this would return `60, 600` instead of `50, 0` .

Comment: @Scrutinizer: Thank you. I've updated the answer to fix that bug, and another that printed only a comma when there were `x` values not in the range `50`-`90`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '$1>=50 && $1<=90{if(!i){i=$1;m=$2}else if(($2+0)<m){m=$2;i=$1}}END{print i","m}' file.csv
```

output:

```
50, 500
```

Comment: Suppose the range and file content would be such that x values range between -10 and 10 and the `(x,y)` values are `(-10,100)`, `(0,0)` and `(100,100)` , then it would return `10, 100` instead of `0, 0` . The trouble is with `if(!i)`

Comment: @Scrutinizer you are right. it could be fixed if OP has this case.

Comment: I made a typo in my comment: `(100,100)` should be `(10,100)`

Answer (score 0):

Another one to try, assuming the x points are listed in order:

```
awk '$1>e{exit} $1>=b && ($2<=m || !s){s=1; m=$2; n=$1} END{print n,m}' b=50 e=90 FS=, OFS=, file
```